# How to change the own variable of a breed to another breed in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I was trying to personB's own variable to update in personA's own list type variable. when I tried to run this code i recived an error message "PERSONB breed does not own variable LEDGER
error while personbs 1 running LEDGER,  called by procedure UPDATE-LEDGER...."
I cant change the ownership(If I make it global others can alter). how can I solve this?

My code is:

```
breed [personAs personA]

breed [personBs personB]

personAs-own [
 wallet
 ledger
]

personBs-own [
 packid
 batch-num
]


to start
 ca

 create-personAs 1 [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "person"
  set ledger []
 ]

 create-personBs 1 [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "person"
  set packid 10
  set batch-num who
 ]

 update-ledger
end


to update-ledger
 ask personBs [
  set ledger fput (list packid batch-num) ledger
 ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im still new to netlogo therefore Im not pretty clear on turtles-own things. If you can please further explain that " making a variable something-own simply means that those are the agents carrying that variable."

let's say if personA owns bookA(list type) and personB owns bookB(list type). personA and personB both cant access other's Books without owner's permission. if personB wants to modify personA's book how can we do this in netlogo?

Comment: Just seen this comment, hope that this reply can reach you in time. As I said in the main answer, a `personB` can modify a `personA` own variable by using `ask` or `of`. Please refer to the code example I posted in the main answer, where I show both the "Solution with `ask`" and the "Solution with `of`". Let me know if something in particular is not clear from there (although we should talk about this in the comment to that reply)

Answer (score 0):

[Before starting: please note that in NetLogo breeds are defined first in their collective form and later in their individual form, e.g. `breed [cats cat]` instead of `breed [cat cats]`, so you should change your breeds declarations accordingly. I'll give my answer as if you used the correct declaration, e.g. `breed [personAs personA]`. Also, note that breeds in NetLogo are not sensible to lower/upper case, so in general you might also want to give more meaningful names to make it easier to read]

--

It is possible to change turtles' breed by just asking them to

```
set breed newbreed
```

This will change their breed and, accordingly, all their breed-own variables (i.e. the turtle will lose its previous breed's variables and will gain its new breed's variables).

However your problem seems to be more fundamental: why did you make `ledger` a `personAs-own` variable if you want `personBs` to use `set ledger`? This is the crucial point.

There are two possibilities here:

1. You want each turtle to have a `ledger` to operate on. In that case, `ledger` must not be a `personAs-own` variable; it has to be a `turtles-own` variable (or, if in your full model you have other breeds who do not need `ledger`, then make it **both** a `personAs-own` and `personBs-own` variable). In any case, no global variables involved (a global variable only has one value for everyone, so that's not what you need).
2. You want `personBs` to be able to operate on the `ledger` of `personAs`. In that case, `personBs` will have to `ask personAs` to modify their `ledger`; or, alternatively, some `personBs` can operate on the `ledger` of some `personAs` by indeed using the `of` reporter ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of)); for example:

```
; Solution with 'ask':
ask one-of personBs [
 ask one-of personAs [
  set ledger 10000
 ]
]

; Solution with 'of':
ask one-of personBs [
 set [ledger] of one-of personAs 10000
]
```

### Important update

Your expression "If I make it global others can alter" suggests me that you're thinking in terms of other programming languages, where you classify variables based on the level of access to that variable that other parts of the programme have.

Note that this is not the case in NetLogo: all parts of the programme (in this case: all agents) have access (even if indirect) to every variable through `ask` and/or `of`. No matter whether a variable is `turtles-own`, `links-own`, `breed-own` or `patches-own`. Every agent can read any other agent's variables. But also: every agent can modify any other agent's variables (see the code examples that I made regarding point 2 above). Therefore, making a variable `something-own` simply means that those are the agents carrying that variable.